# Akka actors - sharing responsibility

Tags: scala, akka, actor

if I understood correctly the best way to process tasks for which multiple actors are needed is to send a message to actor 1, let him do his work and let actor 1 send a message to actor 2, let him do his work and let actor 2 send a message either to the user or to a third actor, etc.

For example, when for some task it's needed to get a dataset definition from disk, process it, transform the result and send the results back to the user. Actor 1 would get the dataset definition from disk, transform it into a JSON, send the result to actor 2 which processes the JSON and then sends the results back to the user.

But then the complete task to process the dataset definition is divided over two actors, is this really the best way to do these kind of things?

To complete the tasks, both actor 1 and 2 should know about the task while actor 1 doesn't do anything about it other then getting the definition from disk and send it to the second actor.

How does one normally do this?

thanks in advance,
Richard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read this [link](https://www.chrisstucchio.com/blog/2013/actors_vs_futures.html). Although your scenario could be implemented in that way you describe there so many details to take in account. If you want concurrency consider using futures, if you want sequential processing use monadic structures.